# How can i get sudo alias in bashrc to work

Tags: linux

I'm trying to create an alias for when I forget to write sudo.

```
sudo !!
```

It works in Terminal but not when I write it as an alias in the bashrc file.

```
alias f='sudo !!'
```

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have in my .bashrc

```
alias f='sudo $(history -p !!)'
```